# How associations get defined when code is baked in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I was trying to bake the blog tutorial in console. I created one table named posts and baked the code and all MVC files were created properly. Then I created another table named comments and I again baked the code but no relationship gets defined by baking and comments was created as separate part from blog. I want to define has many relationship means blog has many comments. How will it get defined through console? Please give some idea? Or am I running bake incorrectly? Many thanks.

Comment: If you will have foreign key assign to your table like *blog_id* than cake bake console automatically ask you to define relationship at time of baking that table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-bake your posts model for this to get correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could either re-bake your models, which will solve it. But eventually you won't be able to. In the ideal situation all the tables are there when you bake it. But usually things change later on. So you should be able to add relations manually as well, which in this case might be faster.

The relation is probably missing in the `Post` model. This is because when baking, it checks other tables for foreign keys that refer to the new model. When the table is not there yet, it won't find it obviously.

I would add the following code in `Post.php`:

```
public $hasMany = array('Comment');
```

If there's already a `$hasMany`, you'll have to add it to the existing array.